# Parse Json response using JObject into error custom object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have an HttpClient.PostAsync method that returns error and I want to parse the response into a custom error object.

json response:

```
{
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "ErrorCode": "RegularExpression",
        "Message": "'Color' can contain only latin, numeric characters and the symbol #.",
        "Errors": [
            {
                "ErrorCode": "RegularExpression",
                "FieldName": "Color",
                "Message": "'Color' can contain only latin, numeric characters and the symbol #.",
                "Meta": {
                    "RegularExpression": "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$",
                    "PropertyName": "Color Code",
                    "PropertyValue": "adadad"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Custom error class:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public FieldErrors[] Errors { get; set; }
}

public class FieldErrors
{ 
    public string ErrorCode {get; set; }
    public string FieldName {get; set; }
    public string Message {get; set; }
}
```

The code for parsing:

```
   var respCont = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();
   var errorResponse = respCont["ResponseStatus"].ToObject<ErrorResponse>();
```

error I get:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'Errors'
```

Comment: You're asking to *transform*, not deserialize. That's not what parsers and serializers do. Use classes that actually match the JSON document, then map the results to whatever you want

Comment: You can easily generate the JSON classes in Visual Studio if you copy the JSON text and then use the [Paste JSON or XML as classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022) commands

Comment: Didn't you ask the same thing yesterday? The types must match. That's what yesterday's answer shows too. You change the types in this question so the types no longer match

Comment: Hi @pikk, which line makes such error? If i hard coded the respCont value with your shared json, it works fine without any error. It is better for you to share how is your api code like. Besides, what is your .net core version?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` traceback of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?  I can deserialize the JSON shown with the data model shown, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/SFXJWD, so it seems that either something is going wrong inside `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>()`, or the JSON in your question is not the actual JSON being returned.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument`

```
public static void Main()
{
    var json = """
            {
                "ResponseStatus": {
                    "ErrorCode": "RegularExpression",
                    "Message": "'Color' can contain only latin, numeric characters and the symbol #.",
                    "Errors": [
                        {
                            "ErrorCode": "RegularExpression",
                            "FieldName": "Color",
                            "Message": "'Color' can contain only latin, numeric characters and the symbol #.",
                            "Meta": {
                                "RegularExpression": "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$",
                                "PropertyName": "Color Code",
                                "PropertyValue": "adadad"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
            """;

    var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    var error = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("ResponseStatus").Deserialize<ErrorResponse>();

}

public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public FieldErrors[] Errors { get; set; }
}

public class FieldErrors
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RsZzJX

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need meta data, one class would be enough

```
using Newtonsoft.Json

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

ResponseStatus responseStatus = JObject.Parse(json)["ResponseStatus"]
                                               .ToObject<ResponseStatus>();

public class ResponseStatus
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<ResponseStatus> Errors { get; set; }
}
```